# What is the point of using references to variables instead of using the actual variable?

Tags: c++, reference, pass-by-reference

I'm pretty new to C++ and I cannot seem to grasp why we would use a referee to a variable instead of just using the variable itself.

```
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
    using namespace std;
    int ival = 1024;
    int &refVal = ival;
    cout << ival << endl << refVal << ends;
    return 0;
}
```

What is the point of the reference if it only ever gives the value of ival? Why not just use ival?

Comment: How would you write a copy constructor?

Comment: In the example you give, there's no benefit. There are plenty of places where you need to refer to objects without copying them though. Any time you need to pass a big object into another function for example.

Comment: This is a really good [tutorial on references](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/references.html)